# vim choked when gdb program outputs too many in termianl-debug mode

Tags: vim, gdb

The `terminal-debug` feature of vim 8 brings a good interface for gdb/vim integration. I've been using it for a while, and so far so good except one annoying performance issue: it seems vim consumes CPU a lot to handle the output from the program being debugged.

One workaround is redirect the output of the program to some file, i.e. `run > /tmp/run.log`; leaving "gdb program" buffer empty. But it's not an ideal way in any sense.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which Vim version are you using? [This](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2179) related issue is on the GitHub tracker.

Summary: v8.0.1170 fixes the reported problem in the given issue. Check if you have it with `:echo has('patch-8.0.1170')`. If you do, and the problem persists, then reopen the issue; if not, update Vim.

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May 13 2019 20:18:02). The `echo has('patch-8.0.1170')` returns 1.

Comment: Thanks to point me to the vim github depot. I'll report there.